# Where to put Aptana Studio on Ubuntu after downloading?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, icons

I am new to Ubuntu so I'm not sure where stuff usually goes. I am pretty sure I have Java 6 installed and working correctly. I have downloaded Aptana Studio 1.5 from their website, unzipped the archive, now it's just sitting on my desktop. I launched the executable from inside the archive and it seems to be working fine.

But there is no "installer", so where should I put the files I just extracted? And how do I create an icon in the applications drop down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to leave it local, just throw it in your home directory (or if you'd rather put it somewhere more "central", I'd suggest `/opt/aptana/`).

You can add items to the applications drop-down by right-clicking on the "applications" (before opening it) and select "Edit Menus". Go to the menu you want and click "New Item".

Answer (score 2):

/usr/local is also a reasonable place to install software without using apt.

If it's a single executable file, a "bin" directory is the best place (eg /usr/local/bin, /opt/aptana/bin, ~/bin).